# Python turtle window closes immediately after running from desktop

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have recently coded 'snake' in python. I can run it from my IDE perfectly fine. However, on my desktop, I right click the file and 'open with python3.9' The window pops up but then immediatley closes. I've tried adding 'input()' at the end but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please update your question adding some of your code. Otherwise it's difficult to help.

Comment: first try to run it in console/terminal (not in IDE) using `python3.9 script.py` - maybe you will see error messages.